# Ordering of product of probabilities

Tags: probability

Let $p_i \in [0,0.5],~ \forall i=1,\ldots,N$ be probabilities of independent events $i=1,\ldots,N$. Let us collect the outcome of events into vectors: $(b_1,\ldots,b_n),~ b_i\in\{0,1\}$, i.e., $b_i=1$ if event $i$ has happened and $0$ otherwise. Sort the outcome vectors in decreasing order according to probability.

If I'm not mistaken this is an NP hard problem, but are there any heuristic algorithms to solve it, or get a partial solution? E.g., find the first $k$ event vectors with the highest probabilities (maybe with some margin of error).

Seems like a pretty classical question, but I haven't found any answers.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are events $1, ... ,N$ independent on each other? Guess that the probability of an outcome vector is simply $\prod_{i=1}^N [(2p_i-1)b_i + 1 - p_i]$. Than, you can sort the vectors. Not sure if I got your question correctly, though.

Comment: I should've mentioned that they are indeed independent, fixed this now. Your formula is correct, the problem here is that we have $2^N$ cases. Simply calculating the probabilities of all the cases and then sorting them is not be feasible when $N$ gets large.

Comment: If you take the negative logs of all of the multiplicands in the comment from @nicola, maybe you can turn it into a [subset sum sorting problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234242/algorithms-for-sorting-subset-sums)?

Comment: Ok, so you want a ranking of all the possible outcome vectors? Is that correct?

Comment: @BrianTung The idea of using logarithms crossed my mind, I don't know how to proceed from there, but it might be easier to tackle. As I take it, the merge sort in your link still takes $O(2^N)$ steps.

Comment: @nicola Yes, that's the basic idea, but I can (and most likely have to) settle for less:) Practically, the important thing would be to sort the high probability outcomes.

Comment: @PlacetExperiri: I think that's right (NP complete), but there are more effective heuristics in the average case.